# sh - running a class file in maven project using shell script

Tags: java, bash, shell, maven

I am new to writing shell scripts and was trying to write a small script to run a class file in a maven project using following shell script :

```
function cleanup() {
   kill ${SERVER_PID} ${CLIENT_PID}
   rm -f cp.txt
}

trap cleanup EXIT

mvn test dependency:build-classpath -Dmdep.outputFile=cp.txt
CLASSPATH=$(cat cp.txt):target/classes
java -classpath ${CLASSPATH} com.practice.Server &
SERVER_PID=$$

while ! nc localhost 1111 > /dev/null 2>&1 < /dev/null; do
    echo "$(date) - waiting for server at localhost:1111..."
    sleep 1
done

java -classpath ${CLASSPATH} com.practice.Client
CLIENT_PID=$$
cleanup
```

But I keep getting

> waiting for server at localhost:1111

with error :

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.paractice.Server
```

Note :  This sh file is present in project folder i.e. parallel to src and target folder.

Please help !!!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `exec` plugin.

Instead of:

```
mvn test dependency:build-classpath -Dmdep.outputFile=cp.txt
CLASSPATH=$(cat cp.txt):target/classes
java -classpath ${CLASSPATH} com.practice.Server &
```

you can do:

```
mvn test exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.practice.Server
```

This will run your program synchronously.

You can change that by either adding the ampersand (`&`) at the end

or

use `mvn exec:exec`, which can run asynchronously:

```
mvn test exec:exec -Dexec.async=true -Dexec.executable="java" -Dexec.args="-classpath %classpath com.practice.Server"
```

Full description of the plugin is available at http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/index.html